# Width and height percentage css IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

So i have an image with css style:

```
#myimage1
{
width:95%;
height:95%;
}
```

Works well on any browser except from (a specific version?) of IE8.

In IE8 the image width and height not only can't be reduced to 95% but the image appears streched and has bigger size than the real image!

Is there another way or i have to use specific values for width and height?

Answer (score 0):

This code seems ok. I think the problem might be somewhere else, for example in the styling of the parent of this image element.

To translate relative sizes into absolute ones, the DOM tree is traversed up until a sized parent is found. Therefor, make sure the size of the parent element is properly set.